# Python:Child process exits leaving its thread running

Tags: python, multithreading, process, python-multithreading

While working on a project using the `multiprocessing` module in python I observed some strange behaviour.

Lets assume that my main program **p1** created a process **p2** using `multiprocessing` module. The process **p2** created a thread in itself called **p2_t1**. There is no code block in **p2** after creating this thread, so it exits(i am NOT calling exit, so it would just return from main) leaving **p2_t1** dangling. I can confirm this via `strace`

Example code in **p1** that creates a child process

```
p = Process(target=RunService,args=(/*some args*/),name="p2")
```

Example code of **p2**:

```
def RunService():
    try:
        /*do something here*/
    except Exception,e:
        /*create a new thread*/

    /*nothing here so basically this process exits leaving the thread dangling*/
```

This however does not happen if a thread(call is **p1_t1**) is created within **p1**. **p1** doesnot exit until the created thread **p1_t1** runs.

Example code in this case for **p1**

```
try:
  /*do something here*/
except Exception,e:
  /*create a new thread*/

    /*nothing here so basically process should end*/
```

In this case the process doesnot exit and keeps running until the thread is running. Any explanations?

Comment: Use backticks (`\``) for inline code, not bold.

Comment: it was not code so i thought of bolding :)..will comply next time

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to speak of, it is hard to tell what's happening, but I would try making your thread a daemon thread and then wait on it with p2.  When the tread finished, then p2 should shut down properly, killing off the thread. Something like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=somefunc, args=((2,)))
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
t1.join()
```

good luck,  Mike

Comment: The example code describes it accurately. The process functions are exactly like this. I was interested in knowing about the difference. Child process `p2` is able to exit even if its thread is running. But `p1` does not exit until its thread ends. `p1` is the process that is created when I launch my program with `python myservice`. Is this behaviour because of the python interpreter calling the first level process?